# Home-brew installation of LAPACKe

Tags: homebrew, installation-package

I've been trying to find the right package to install so that I can use

```
#include <lapacke.h>
```

but I've not been able to find a home-brew command that once downloaded contains this library. Is it possible to download this using home-brew, if not what our my alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Accelerate ships with OS X and provides LAPACK: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/LAPACK.7.html

Alternatively, the homebrew/science/openblas package provides a LAPACK implementation.

Comment: I think this answer is not a good answer. This user wants "LAPACKE", with an "e". This is a C interface for LAPACK.

Comment: Accelerate provides a C interface for LAPACK.